# C# SqlClient connection open in thread - SqlException not caught

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, sqlconnection, sqlexception

I have implemented `SqlClient` connecting function with timeout parameter. It means, that `connection.open()` is in another thread and after thread is started, I'm checking elapsed time. If the time had reached timeout, thread is aborted and no connection is established.

The thing is, that if I have timeout bigger then default `connection.open()` timeout, `open()` throws `SqlException`, which isn't caught in my `Catch(SqlException)` block.

I'm starting whole connecting process in another thread:

```
public void connect()
{
    Thread connectThread = new Thread(waitForTimeout);
    connectThread.Start();
}
```

Connecting thread -> starts another thread for timeout waiting

```
public void waitForTimeout()
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectString);

    Thread timeoutThread = new Thread(openConnection);
    timeoutThread.Start();

    DateTime quitTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(timeout);
    while (DateTime.Now < quitTime)
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            transac = connection.BeginTransaction();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Transaction = transac;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        timeoutThread.Interrupt();
}
```

Here exception isn't caught after open() default timeout:

```
private void openConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        // This isn't caught anytime
    }
}
```

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: This is a bad pattern. `SqlConnection` supports connection timeout settings right out of the box, why are you trying to do the same thing in a convoluted and non-functioning way? There is no way to abort a thread that is not in managed code (and even aborting while in managed code is very much frowned upon). Not to mention that `Interrupt` doesn't do what you think it does. And spinning the cpu in a while cycle is also a silly way to wait for the connection to be opened. Is `SqlConnection` even thread-safe? I wouldn't think so...

Comment: `SqlConnection` is most certainly not thread safe. Sharing it across threads is a pretty bad idea, and is sure to get you into trouble.

Slightly off topic: Use the Tasks API rather than using threads directly. Using the low level threading API directly is obsolete style for most use cases.

Comment: Seriously, throwing more threads at a problem rarely helps. Learn how to use `SqlConnection` properly, make use of the asynchronous methods, learn something about how multi-threading works and how to use signalling, handle synchronization etc. Multi-threading is a very complicated and complex problem, not a simple solution to a problem with blocking.

Comment: I tried to add timeout to connection string, but it doesn't work. Of course I have been looking for some cleaner solution. `Task` is also problem, because I'm supposed to make it working with .NET 3.5. And even if timeout in `SqlConnection` works, I need to run in another thread because of app freezing while connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comments I tried to implement new solution, and here it is:

Constructor:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
public Database(string source, string database, string user, string password,
    int timeout, DelegateConnectionResult connectResult)
{
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.connectResult = connectResult;

    connectString = "server=" + source +
          ";database=" + database +
          ";uid=" + user + 
          ";pwd=" + password + 
          ";connect timeout=" + Convert.ToInt16(timeout / 1000);
}
```

Asynchonous connect:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
public void connectAsync()
{
    connectThread = new Thread(connectSync);
    connectThread.Start();
}
```

Synchronous connect:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
public void connectSync()
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        transac = connection.BeginTransaction();
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Transaction = transac;

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connectResult(true);
        else
            connectResult(false);
    }
    catch
    {
        connectResult(false);
    }
}
```

And I found the solution for original problem witch SqlException from this post: it has something to do with Exceptions settings in debugger of Visual Studio. If I unchecked "throw" choice at SqlException in Exceptions list (CTRL + D + E in Visual Studio), I'm finally able to catch exception.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it caught or isn't it thrown? Thread.start only schedules the thread for running but doesn't mean it will start immediately. Maybe code runs till threadTimeout interruption, then openConnection starts and always succeed to open the connection within default timeout.

---edit

In this case maybe could you try to:

1. replace `SqlException` by `Exception` and check if you catch something such as `ThreadInterruptedException` instead
2. put the content of openConnection method in your waitForTimeout method right after `connection = new SqlConnection(connectString);` (and comment the rest of the code) and see if exception is still not handled. If not, then put it in the `connect()` method and check again.

Comment: No, I have stopped sql server for sure. connection.open() throws SqlException after some time, but it isn't caught in my catch block, so it's unhandled.

Comment: Yeah I tried to run without thread and also tried to catch Exception, but also without effect. Now I noticed that it's something with Exceptions settings in debugger. If I unchecked "throw" choice at SqlException in Exceptions list (CTRL + D + E in Visual Studio), I'm finally able to catch exception!